# How to create CMakeList for xv6-riscv operation system from Makefile?

Tags: makefile, operating-system, clion, cmakelists-options

I want to create CMakeList.txt for CLion IDE for the current changed xv6-ricv operation system:
https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv

I tried without success. Is there a way for CLion or another thirds party software will create it for me? Or maybe exists one?

Makefile:
https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/Makefile

Because without that CLion can't recognize the structure of the project and a lot of features can't be used as a result.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to mark your project as src. Right click on the project folder and say Mark Directory As -> Sources